# StaleElementReferenceException issue while scraping with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to load this page in full: https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1

I've set a line of code to handle the cookies popup.

Then I've set some lines to click on the Load More Results button in order to have the full html loaded and then printing it.

But I hit an error message after it clicked once :

```
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I don't know what it means nor how to fix it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

site = 'https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1'
wd = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
wd.get(site)

time.sleep(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)

# click cookies popup
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[(@id = "description")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "tc-open-privacy-center", " " ))]').click()

time.sleep(10)

# click show more button until no more results to load
while True:
    try:
        more_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'AFFICHER LES 20 OFFRES SUIVANTES'))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        break

time.sleep(10)

print(wd.page_source)
print("Complete")

time.sleep(10)
wd.quit()
```

Comment: use execute_script() i think that is more realiable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to handle stale element reference.

One is like try to re-click on the web element in a while loop.

Your link_text also looks wrong, Please use the below xpath :

```
# click cookies popup
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[(@id = "description")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "tc-open-privacy-center", " " ))]').click()

time.sleep(10)

# click show more button until no more results to load
while True:
    try:
        more_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@onclick,'tagDeClick') and contains(@href,'/offres/emploi.rechercheoffre:afficherplusderesultats')]")))
        ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(more_button).perform()
        attempts = 0
        while attempts < 2 :
            try:
                more_button.click()
                break
            except StaleElementReferenceException as exception:
                print(exception.msg)
            attempts = attempts  + 1

    except TimeoutException:
        break

time.sleep(10)

print(driver.page_source)
print("Complete")

time.sleep(10)
```

**Output :**

```
stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

If you see this in `logs`, and you do not wish to see this, you will have to comment `print(exception.msg)`.

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an idea why I have a  undefined name 'StaleElementReferenceException' at the line except StaleElementReferenceException as exception ?

Comment: you have to import `from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException` this should help you past the undefined exception.

Answer (score 2):

> StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is
> not attached to the page document

Indicates that a reference to an element is now "stale" --- the element no longer appears on the DOM of the page. The reason for this expectation is may be your `DOM` got updated or refreshed. For an example, after performing an action like `click()` your `DOM` may get updated or refreshed. In this time when you are trying to find an element on `DOM` you will experience this error.

You have to re-find that element in updated or refreshed `DOM`

```
       try:  
            more_button = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'AFFICHER LES 20 OFFRES SUIVANTES'))).click()  
     except StaleElementReferenceException:
            more_button = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'AFFICHER LES 20 OFFRES SUIVANTES')))
            more_button.click()
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned at what line the exception occurs. Please see and add this exception handling at that step.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the execute_script method i think it is the most reliable method to solve this kind of problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

site = 'https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1'
wd = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
wd.get(site)

time.sleep(10)

wait = WebDriverWait(wd, 10)

# click cookies popup
wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[(@id = "description")]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "tc-open-privacy-center", " " ))]').click()

time.sleep(10)

# click show more button until no more results to load
while True:
    try:
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'AFFICHER LES 20 OFFRES SUIVANTES')))
        more_button = wd.find_element_by_link_text('AFFICHER LES 20 OFFRES SUIVANTES')
        wd.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', more_button)
        #print('clicked')
    except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException):
        break

time.sleep(10)

print(wd.page_source)
print("Complete")

time.sleep(10)
wd.quit()
```